# join 2 consecutive rows under condition

Tags: sed, awk

### I have 5 lines like:

```
typeA;pointA1
typeA;pointA2
typeA;pointA3
typeB;pointB1
typeB;pointB2
```

### result output would be:

```
typeA;pointA1;typeA;pointA2
typeA;pointA2;typeA;pointA3
typeB;pointB1;typeB;pointB2
```

Is it possible to use sed or awk for this purpose?

Comment: Are the empty lines between the records part of the real input?

Comment: The sequence of colons and semicolons in the output seems a little odd. Is it correct? I've answered assuming it is.

Comment: The Colons are mistyping - they should be replaced by ';'

Answer (score 2):

This is easy with awk:

```
awk -F';' '$1 == prevType { printf("%s;%s;%s\n", $1, prevPoint, $0) } { prevType = $1; prevPoint = $2 }'
```

I've assumed that the blank lines between the records are not part of the input; if they are, just run the input through `grep -v '^$'` before awk.

Comment: Can you please explain what your script does Michael? I am learning awk and would be really helpful. +1 for the answer :)

Comment: @DawnoftheDead The script tracks the two fields of the records as the `prevType` and `prevPoint`. As a new record is encountered, the first field of the record - the type - is compared against `prevType`, printing a formatted combination of the current and previous records when the two type fields are the same. The second action always occurs, just updating the prev- fields to those of the record just checked.

Answer (score 1):

paste could be useful in this case. it could save a lot of codes:

```
sed '1d' file|paste -d";" file -|awk -F';' '$1==$3'
```

see the **test** below

```
kent$  cat a
typeA;pointA1
typeA;pointA2
typeA;pointA3
typeB;pointB1
typeB;pointB2

kent$  sed '1d' a|paste -d";" a -|awk -F';' '$1==$3'
typeA;pointA1;typeA;pointA2
typeA;pointA2;typeA;pointA3
typeB;pointB1;typeB;pointB2
```

Answer (score 0):

This GNU sed solution might work for you:

```
 sed -rn '1{h;b};H;x;/^([^;]*);.*\n\1/!{s/.*\n//;x;d};s/\n/;/p' source_file
```

Assumes no blank lines else pipe preformat the source file with `sed '/^$/d' source_file`

EDIT:

On reflection the above solution is far too elaborate and can be condensed to:

```
 sed -ne '1{h;b};H;x;/^\([^;]*\);.*\1/s/\n/;/p' source_file
```

Explanation:

The `-n` prevents any lines being implicitly printed. The first line is copied to the hold space (HS an extra register) and then a break is made that ends the iteration. All subsequent lines are appended to the HS. The HS is then swapped with the pattern space (PS - a register holding the current line). The HS at this point contains the previous and current lines which are now checked to see if the first field in each line are identical. If so, the newline separating the two lines is replaced by a `;` and providing the substitution occurred the PS is printed out. The next iteration now takes place, the current line refreshes the PS and HS now holds the previous line.

Comment: Small remark: Missing ';' sign. Example: typeA;pointA1typeA;pointA2 it should be typeA;pointA1;typeA;pointA2

Comment: Thanks to @Kent for making me reflect on my muddied solution