# join 2 lines only if field-1 are equals with sed or awk

Tags: sed, awk

input file:

```
$ cat t.txt
id1;value1_1
id1;value1_2
id2;value2_1
id3;value3_1
id4;value4_1
id4;value4_2
id5;value5_1
```

result would be:

```
id1;value1_1;id1;value1_2
id3;value3_1
id4;value4_1;id4;value4_2
id5;value5_1
```

using sed or awk. Please give your opinion.

Comment: Is a requirement to use that commands? This can be done in bash with a for loop.

Comment: the first choice is using awk or sed

Comment: btw, you have asked two quite similar questions so far. have you considered to accept correct answers for your questions? the other question from you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8103167/join-2-consecutive-rows-under-condition

Comment: Correct, but using the previous awk statement, lines like id2;value2_1 , id3;value3_1, .. are not printed

Comment: If you're not getting the answer you desire, it is probably because you're not providing the right information in your question. Please read this excellent guide: http://tinyurl.com/so-hints . Please work on improving existing questions, rather than rephrasing them as new ones.

Answer (score 6):

Here's one way to do it:

```
awk -F';' 'BEGIN { getline; id=$1; line=$0 } { if ($1 != id) { print line; line = $0; } else { line = line ";" $0; } id=$1; } END { print line; }' t.txt
```

Explanation:

Set field separator to `;`:

```
-F';'
```

Start by reading the first line of input (`getline`), save the first field (`$1`) as `id`, and the first line (`$0`) as `line`:

```
BEGIN { getline; id=$1; line=$0 }
```

For each line of input, check if the first field differs from the stored id:

```
if ($1 != id)
```

If it does, then print the saved line and store the new one (`$0`):

```
print line; line = $0;
```

Otherwise, append the new line to the stored line(s):

```
line = line ";" $0;
```

And save the new id:

```
id=$1
```

At the end, print whatever is left in `line`:

```
END { print line; }
```

Comment: It's customary to mark an answer as correct, when it is. =) You can read more about how to do that in the FAQ.

Answer (score 2):

I guess in your result example, the id2; line is missing by mistake, right?

anyway, you could try the awk line below:

```
awk -F';' '{a[$1]=($1 in a)?a[$1]";"$0:$0}END{for(x in a)print a[x]}' yourFile|sort
```

output would be:

```
id1;value1_1;id1;value1_2
id2;value2_1
id3;value3_1
id4;value4_1;id4;value4_2
id5;value5_1
```

Comment: that is correct; the id2 line should be added. It works. Thank you

Comment: small remark: the result shows the beginning of each line a ';' char.

Comment: ;id1;value1_1;id1;value1_2
;id2;value2_1
;id3;value3_1
;id4;value4_1;id4;value4_2
;id5;value5_1

Comment: $ awk -F';' '{a[$1]=($1 in a)?a[$1]";"$0:$0}END{for(x in a)print a[x]}' < t.txt


;id1;value1_1;id1;value1_2
;id2;value2_1
;id3;value3_1
;id4;value4_1;id4;value4_2
;id5;value5_1

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
 sed -e '1{h;d};H;${x;:a;s/\(\([^;]*;\)\([^\n]*\)\)\n\2/\1;\2/;ta;p};d' t.txt
```

Explanation:

Slurp file in to hold space (HS) then on end-of-file swap to the HS and using substitution concatenate lines with duplicate keys  and print. N.B. lines normally printed are all deleted.

EDIT:

The above solution works (as far as I know) but for large volumes is not very fast (read incredibly slow). This solution is better:

```
# cat -A /tmp/t.txt 
id1;value1_1$
id1;value1_2$
id2;value2_1$
id3;value3_1$
id4;value4_1$
id4;value4_2$
id5;value5_1$
# for x in {1..1000};do cat /tmp/t.txt;done | 
> sed ':a;$!N;/^\([^;]*;\).*\n\1/s/\n//;ta;P;D'| sort | uniq
id1;value1_1;id1;value1_2
id2;value2_1
id3;value3_1
id4;value4_1;id4;value4_2
id5;value5_1
```

Comment: Damn!! you are like the master of SED, potong. Any suggestions on good references?

Comment: First thank you for the effort. For small number of lines e.g. 77 lines this solution is OK. But for large number of lines e.g. 1200 lines, the result shows like:<br/> id1;value1_1<br/>;id1;value1_2<br/><br/> So the joining doesnot take place (i have problem with the comment editor - the <br/> does not result in '\n')

Comment: @user1042891 See EDIT - I've improved the solution and tested at volumes above 1200 lines. Data is tricky stuff it doesn't always respect your wishes and may need cleaning up beforehand.

Comment: `$ for x in {1..1000};do cat t.txt;done | sed -e ':a;N;s/^\([^;]*;\)\([^\n]*\)\n\1/\1\2;\1/;ta;P;D'| sort | uniq  ===>result:
;id1;value1_2
id1;value1_2
id2;value2_1
id3;value3_1
;id4;value4_2
id5;value5_1
id5;value5_1id1;value1_1` <br> I have a different result

Comment: @user1042891 As I said please check your data. Try `cat -A t.txt`. May be you have some strange characters in amongst or at start/end of line.

Comment: `t.txt: each line ends with <CR><NL> char's. After executing the sed command, the result in case the joining condition is met results in: <line N><CR>;<line N+1><CR><NL>. So it explains why the result using a text editor are different. I have to strip-off the <CR> char for each line in t.txt. Note <CR> = 0x0d, <NL> = 0x0a